# Java Regex matching not working with spaces

Tags: java, regex

I want to check the string contains `ST=`. there may be spaces before/after `ST` and `=`.

so i have regex match as `"\\s*ST\\s*=\\w+"`, but it doesn't work. Any thoughts?

```
String REG_MATCH = "\\s*ST\\s*=\\w+";
String value =" ST= CA"

if (value.matches(REG_MATCH)){
  --matched
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Include optional space before and after `=`**:

```
String REG_MATCH = "\\s*ST\\s*=\\s*\\w+";
```

#### [Java RegEx Demo](http://fiddle.re/e3jxt)

Comment: the extra slash was formatting issue with this editor. I have only 2 slashes, it doesn't work